# How to store key, value in Amazon Cognito?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a model that needs to be saved into Cognito. 
How would be optimal to store a model?

```
struct Puzzle {
    let puzzleId: String
    let completed: Bool
    let time: Date
    let hints: Int
    let state: State
    let history: String
}
```

It seems inefficient to concatenate all model properties into a string.

Comment: I think, it is good to use DynamoDB, having keys as puzzleID and have an identifier for puzzleID in cognito.

Comment: @sailesh, I would want to limit the frameworks used into the app. But I'll look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to store key value pairs which are required to be accessed only by a particular user and cross device synchronization is required for these key value pairs, you can use [Amazon Cognito Sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-sync.html).

Amazon Cognito Sync lets you save end user data in datasets containing key-value pairs. This data is associated with an Amazon Cognito identity, so that it can be accessed across logins and devices. This data between the Amazon Cognito service and an end user’s devices can be synced by invoking the synchronize method in provided the client library.

Comment: What I can do with my complex model? How to save it key:value, to be efficient? I have another model where one of the property is a model.